# How to correct SQL Syntax Error after attempting to replace text

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm afraid I made a novice error while trying to replace text in a MySQL table using phpMyadmin. I wanted to remove `<!--/ .columns -->` within the table `ccadr_field_data_body`

I ran the query:

```
SELECT *  FROM `ccadr_field_data_body` WHERE `bundle` = 'treatments' 
SET `body_value` = replace(body_value, '<!--/ .columns -->', ' ')
```

Since then I get the following error message when trying to view the values in this table within phpMyAdmin:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your     MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET`body_value`=replace(body_value,'',' ') LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Any suggesting on how to roll this back or fix the syntax error?

Comment: Are you trying to `UPDATE` the table or are you trying to `SELECT` from it with modifications?

Comment: I was trying to select within table 'ccadr_field_data_body' only values where the column 'bundle' = 'treatments. Then I wanted to search for '<!--/ .columns -->' within the column 'body_value' in order to remove it.

Comment: At this stage, I'd be happy just to undo the error that I caused with my original query. I don't understand the syntax well enough to know where my query went wrong. Any advice on what my query actually did and how I could roll it back would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to crack this nut. You can either fix it during the retrieval phase, leaving it in the database as-is, or you can repair the database.

To rewrite it on retrieval:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(body_value, '<!--/ .columns -->', ' ') AS body_value
  FROM ccadr_field_data_body
```

It's probably better to expand `*` to the actual column names to avoid any duplication here.

To fix it in the database:

```
UPDATE ccadr_field_data_body
  SET body_value=REPLACE(body_value, '<!--/ .columns -->', ' ')
```

That will permanently modify it, and it could go horribly wrong, so as always, **have backups** before proceeding.